# Could black holes be a three dimensional object breaking through space time and falling 4th dimensionaly

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, spacetime-dimensions

I was thinking about general relativity and I was thinking about it in two dimensions where a heavy metal ball would be placed on a mesh fabric (this is just how I’m imagining it) and if the ball was heavy enough, or concentrated on a small enough point, it would break through the fabric and fall down in the third dimension. Now imagine that you were a two dimensional being, from your perspective a circular object would have been pulled into itself by gravity, and anything that gets too close would also get pulled in. From the perspective of a three dimensional human (us) we can see that the object broke through the fabric and fell down, away from the other two dimensions. Now think about black holes, the mesh fabric is now 3 dimensional and being pulled into any object with mass, if an object of great mass was condensed into a small enough point, maybe the fabric would also break in Three dimensions. And the object would fall in the fourth dimension (a theoretical fourth spacial dimension not the “time is the fourth dimension”) if this is true it could explain why nothing is able to escape, because it is no longer accessible to us in the 3rd dimension. And perhaps all objects contain infinite dimensions but we can only interact with 3 (like how a sphere would look like a circle to a second dimensional creature). Of course even if you tried we couldn't reach the forth dimension because we would die and even if we didn’t we still couldn’t interact with the fourth dimension, but it’s an interesting thought. P.s. this is just my own thoughts and I could be completely wrong and ignorant, but that’s why I’m asking.

Comment: [This help page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) explains this site’s policy regarding personal theories.

Answer (score 2):

Before you ask this kind of question it's a good idea to have some idea of the math behind Relativity.

The distance between two points on a plane is:

$$ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2$$

Should be obvious - this is the Pythagorean theorem. In 3-dimensional space, this becomes:

$$ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$$

In special relativity, we add time as the fourth dimension. In natural units where the speed of light = 1 (note the minus sign):

$$ds^2 = -dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$$

In general relativity, things get a lot more complicated, but we can still write the so-called 'metric' for the simplest black hole, the Schwarzschild black hole (again with c = 1):

$$d s^2 = 
- \left( 1 - \frac{r_\text{s}}{r} \right) dt^{2} + \frac{dr^{2}}{1 - \frac{r_\text{s}}{r}} + r^{2} d\theta^{2} + r^{2} \sin^{2} \theta \, d\phi^{2}$$

Here we use spherical polar coordinates $r, \theta, \phi$ for the spatial coordinates, and $r_s$ is short for $2GM$.

You should immediately be able to notice some things - at $r = 0$, the right hand side blows up. It also blows up at $r = r_s$. Analysis of this is more intricate, but the result is that at $r = 0$, there is a singularity, and $r = r_s$ is the event horizon.

Now try to extrapolate this to "black holes are a three dimensional object breaking through space time and falling in the fourth dimension". How would you even begin to express that in the above equation describing the Schwarzschild black hole? The equation itself has four dimensions, so how do you extract three out of that? How do you "fall" through the last one?

As it is your question is too vague to answer.